# basic c#, asp.net looping and css style

Tags: c#, asp.net, foreach

What do i try to achieve:

Trying to get the following result roughly

[day number]  [FixtureTeamHome] v [FixtureTeamAway]

[month name]  [Shortdescription], [Venue]

On the Page_load I retrieve the Team Details page which has all the fixtures involved
First of all is this the correct way, secondly i got the result needed but how would i add a style this as currently s += "

is not being recognized.

thank you for your advice, help and directions

```
public partial class WebForm6 : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    public string TeamTitle = null;
    public string TeamTitle1 = null;
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DataView TeamRecordSet = (DataView)SqlDataSource1.Select(DataSourceSelectArguments.Empty);
        foreach (DataRowView DRV in TeamRecordSet)
        {
            lblTeamName.Text = DRV["TeamName"].ToString();
            lblTeamNameShortInfo.Text = DRV["TeamShortInfo"].ToString();
            Image1.ImageUrl = "~/style/images/teams/" + DRV["TeamPhoto"].ToString();
        }


        DataView TeamFixtureRecordSet = (DataView)SqlDataSource2.Select(DataSourceSelectArguments.Empty);
        string s = "<ul class=\"latest-posts\" id=\"TeamFIxtures\">";
        foreach (DataRowView DRV1 in TeamFixtureRecordSet)
        {
            int FixtureMonth = (int)DRV1["FixtureMonth"];
            string strMonthName = CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.DateTimeFormat.GetAbbreviatedMonthName(FixtureMonth);
            s += "<li><span class=\"date\"><em class=\"day\">";
            s += "</em><em class=\"month\">" + strMonthName + "</em></span>";

            // Fixture ================================================================

            // Home Team
            int FixtureTeamHomeID = (int)DRV1["FixtureTeamHomeID"];
            TeamNameHome(FixtureTeamHomeID);
            s += "<a href=\"#\">" + TeamTitle + "</a>";

            TeamTitle = null;

            s += " v ";

            // Away Team
            int FixtureTeamAwayID = (int)DRV1["FixtureTeamAwayID"];
            TeamNameAway(FixtureTeamAwayID);
            s += "<a href=\"#\">" + TeamTitle1 + "</a><br />";
            TeamTitle1 = null;

            // Venue
            s += "<a href=\"#\">" + DRV1["FixtureShortInfo"].ToString() + "</a><br /><br />";
            s += "<a href=\"#\">" + DRV1["VenueID"].ToString() + "</a></li>";
        }
        s += "</ul>";
        lblTeamFIxtures.Text = s;
    }

    public void TeamNameHome(int arg1)
    {
        using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(WebConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["WCDB_local"].ConnectionString))
        {
            string sqlSelect = @"select TeamName
                    from Teams 
                    where TeamID = @TeamID";
            using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sqlSelect, conn))
            {
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@TeamID", arg1);
                conn.Open();
                TeamTitle = cmd.ExecuteScalar().ToString();
            }
        }
    }

    public void TeamNameAway(int arg2)
    {
        Int32 myTeamID = arg2;
        using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(WebConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["WCDB_local"].ConnectionString))
        {
            string sqlSelect = @"select TeamName
                    from Teams 
                    where TeamID = @TeamID";
            using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sqlSelect, conn))
            {
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@TeamID", arg2);
                conn.Open();
                TeamTitle1 = cmd.ExecuteScalar().ToString();
            }
        }
    }
```

I think i might have sussed it, and slowly beginning to understand the logic behind it , could i have an opinion if this is the correct way to approach this ? thanks again guys, every little advice helps....

**ASPX FILE:**

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="repeater.aspx.cs" Inherits="WorldCup.repeater" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
<form id="form1" runat="server">
<div>
    <asp:Label ID="lblID" runat="server"></asp:Label><br /><br />

    <asp:Repeater ID="FixtureRepeater" runat="server" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1">
        <ItemTemplate>
            <asp:HyperLink ID="lblTeamNameHome" runat="server" NavigateUrl='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "FixtureTeamHomeID", "?tid={0}") %>'><%# Eval("TEAMHOME") %></asp:HyperLink> v <asp:HyperLink ID="lblTeamNameAway" runat="server" NavigateUrl='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "FixtureTeamAwayID", "?tid={0}") %>'><%# Eval("TEAMAWAY") %></asp:HyperLink><br />
            <asp:Label ID="lblShortdescription" runat="server"><%# Eval("FixtureShortInfo") %></asp:Label><br />
            <asp:HyperLink ID="lblVenue" runat="server" NavigateUrl='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "VenueID", "?tid={0}") %>'><%# Eval("VENUE")%></asp:HyperLink><br /><br />
        </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:Repeater>

    <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" 
        ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:WCDB_local %>" 
        SelectCommand="SELECT Fixtures.FixtureID, Fixtures.GroupID, Fixtures.VenueID, Fixtures.FixtureTime, Fixtures.FixtureDate, Fixtures.FixtureTeamHomeID, Fixtures.FixtureTeamAwayID, Fixtures.FixtureShortInfo, Fixtures.FixtureDescription, Fixtures.FixtureImage, Fixtures.FixtureResult, Teams_1.TeamName AS TEAMHOME, Teams_2.TeamName AS TEAMAWAY, Venues_1.VenueName AS VENUE FROM Fixtures INNER JOIN Teams AS Teams_1 ON Fixtures.FixtureTeamHomeID = Teams_1.TeamID INNER JOIN Teams AS Teams_2 ON Fixtures.FixtureTeamAwayID = Teams_2.TeamID INNER JOIN Venues AS Venues_1 ON Fixtures.VenueID = Venues_1.VenueID WHERE (Fixtures.FixtureTeamHomeID = @id) OR (Fixtures.FixtureTeamAwayID = @id)">
        <SelectParameters>
            <asp:ControlParameter Name="id" Type="Int32" ControlID="lblID" />
        </SelectParameters>
    </asp:SqlDataSource>
</div>
</form>
```

**CS FILE**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Data;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Data.SqlClient;

namespace WorldCup
{
    public partial class repeater : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string v = Request.QueryString["tid"];
            if (v != null)
            {
                lblID.Text = v.ToString();
            }
            else 
            {
                Int32 defaultvalue = 3;
                lblID.Text = defaultvalue.ToString();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

once again thanks for your help and advice, it really helps @ Samjongenelen, thanks for the links

Comment: Use a markup template with a code behind.  Don't generate the HTML as a string.  Use a GridView or a Repeater to display dynamic content, such as the results of a DB query.

Comment: thanks, i have tried various ways, and understand what you are saying however if classic asp (3.0) i was able to do something like

    Do while not objRS.EOF
    If not objRS.EOF Then
      GetTeamName(objrs("TeamID"))
    Else
    End if

How would i create a repeater which include another function or label, that would retrieve the teamName?

Sorry for these newbie questions as i knowthey should be very basic, but cant seem to get the logic yet

Comment: Ask Google.  There are thousands of tutorials on the subject.

Comment: true, but that's hard if you not sure how to approach it, you gave me a direction to look into and now looking at that option. thanks

Answer (score 2):

Basically, you're using ASP classic techniques with some other not so pretty code.

No flame, but this makes the application hard to debug :) So this is not an answer to your question but a lookup tip

IMO a good place to start would be researching data binding / 'Live binding', which is basically creating the (design) skeleton in ASPNET and then binding a datasource to it. 
Easy to implement and maintain

See 
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/8659/Mastering-ASP-NET-DataBinding
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/ee819084.aspx

Comment: Thank you very much, and your right, I'm a old school classic asp developer however always used VB and trying now c# make it even more confusion, but seem to constantly go back to my old ways, which is not my intention.. I had a quick glaze at the 2 links you provided and going to give them a read through, will comment my finding later, thanks for your advice